# Unchecked assignment on Loader

Tags: android

I have the following line of code:

```
public @NonNull Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) { return new Loader(this); }
```

For which I am receiving the following warning on the "new Loader" statement in Android Studio:

"Unchecked assignment: 'andoid.support.v4.content.loader' to 'andoid.support.v4.content.loader<android.database.cursor>'"

Would anyone know how to resolve this warning?

Comment: Did you try `new Loader<Cursor>(...` ?

Comment: Thank you Andy! That works. I should have thought about this. I only actually had to add <>, for adding <Cursor> generates a statement "Explicite type argument Cursor can be replaced by with <>" Thank you for your help.